# Mi ventana de tkinter crea dos ventanas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, imagen, python-3.7

dato gracioso: estaba redactando la pregunta y solucione el error asi que active Responder a tu propia pregunta

Mi ventana envia dos ventanas

La idea era que mostrara "Bienvenido (Imagen) (Usuario)"

Y luego tenia que mostrar una entry y un boton para contraseña

Todo funcionaba perfecto, nada mal, sin errores.

No le agregue absolutamente NADA ni un espacio, NADA y de repente lo ejecuto

Todo bien hasta que salgo del programa por un momento y resulta que habia dos ventanas

Supuse que lo ejecute sin querer dos veces, lo cerre y volvi a abrir pero en vez de mostrar luego de "Bienvenido (Imagen) (Usuario)" luego tenia que poner un entry y en lugar de un boton se abria otra ventana con la misma imagen y me saltaba esto:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Maxi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 804, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "h:\bind.d\apps\enproceso\game_peter\os\main.py", line 55, in entry
    from main import SadroImage
  File "h:\bind.d\apps\enproceso\game_peter\os\main.py", line 50, in <module>
    SadroImage=Label(root,image=SadroPhoto)
  File "C:\Users\Maxi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Maxi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

Esto es lo mas importante del codigo
Nombre del archivo main.py

```
def initializeroot():
    global root
    root=Tk()
    skyblue="#0099FF"
    blue="#0000FF"
    root.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
    global packWelcomeFrame_1
    global welcomeFrame
    global welcomeLabel
    global welcomeLabel2
    packWelcomeFrame_1=root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 -200
    packWelcomeFrame_3=root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 -140
    packWelcomeFrame_4=root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 -140
    packWelcomeFrame_2=root.winfo_screenheight() / 2
    welcomeFrame=Frame(root,width=700,height=600,bg="blue")
    welcomeFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
    welcomeLabel=Label(root,text="Bienvenido a",bg="blue")
    welcomeLabel.place(x=packWelcomeFrame_3,y=200)
    welcomeLabel.config(font=("Sans-Serif",36))
    welcomeLabel2=Label(root,text=f"Usuario {username[0]}")
    welcomeLabel2.place(x=packWelcomeFrame_4,y=500)
    welcomeLabel2.config(font=("Sans-Serif",36),bg="blue")
def getPassword():
    global passwordInput
    passwordInput=passwordEntry.get()
    global passwordResult
    if passwordInput==password[0]:
        passwordResult=True
    else:
        passwordResult=False-
readuserdata()
initializeroot()
SadroPhoto=PhotoImage(file="C:/ProgramData/sysadro/bin/sadro.sadroimage")
SadroImage=Label(root,image=SadroPhoto)
SadroImage.place(x=packWelcomeFrame_1,y=300)
def entry():
    welcomeLabel.destroy()
    welcomeLabel2.destroy()
    from main import SadroImage
    SadroImage.destroy()
    global passwordEntry
    global submitPassword
    xvar=root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 -50
    xvar2=root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 +125
    passwordEntry=Entry(root,width=30,show="●")
    passwordEntry.place(x=xvar,y=200)
    submitPassword=Button(root,text="→",command=getPassword)
    submitPassword.place(x=xvar2,y=200)
    submitPassword.config(font=("Arial"))
root.after(3000,entry)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error es el siguiente

En la funcion entry()

```
from main import SadroImage
```

Importaste el script main en el script main
si sacas la linea funciona